# Laravel breeze react. bundle.js is missing after install

Tags: reactjs, laravel, breeze

I followed the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/starter-kits) on how to install `react` with `breeze` on `laravel`.

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel="9.*" myProject
cd myProject

composer require laravel/breeze --dev

php artisan breeze:install react
 
npm install
npm run dev
php artisan migrate
```

and after that the `console` gives me an error:

```
GET http://localhost:8080/js/bundle.js net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

And after registering, I cannot logout. Probably because `bundle.js` is missing?
How to fix this?

Comment: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/get-httplocalhost8080jsbundlejs-neterr-connection-refused?page=1&replyId=767469